# Updating drivers on a Lenovo T410

Tags: windows-7, drivers, updates, thinkpad

I have a few question regarding updating the drivers on my Lenovo T410.  I have Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit installed with a 32 bit(X86) sub directory. I'm not that familiar with updating drivers on 64bit Windows so I'm wondering if I should install both 32/64 bit driver versions instead of just 64 bit.

Another question I have is Lenovo specific.  On the support page for my device, there is a list of Windows updates available dating back to 2009, however I do have ThinkVantage update manager installed and it checks for Windows updates weekly.  Should I install all of the Windows specific updates, or can I rely on update manager?

My last question is if I should install the drivers for the T410 in any specific order?

Any help is much appreciated as I haven't been able to find answers to these specific questions here, or by googling.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 32 bit drivers will not function fully. Don't use them. Use 64bit if your running a 64bit OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install 64bit drivers for 64bit os. 32bit drivers will usually not work at all (unlike applications).

You should install drivers in an order that corresponds to your common sense. Critical Motherboard/Chipset drivers first, then Video, then everything else. It usually doesn't make a difference but why take a chance?

I would do this before you attempt any Windows Updates. I wouldn't use Lenovo's update manager, just get the drivers directly from the Lenovo website. Also feel free to not install drivers proposed by Windows Update, if you have already installed one from Lenovo that seems recent enough.

If ever you encounter a driver that seems unusually dated (for example, WiFi Driver > 18months) feel free to try the reference drivers from the OEM like intel or broadcom or whatever windows update suggests.